# CURL PHP request para um WEB Service

Tags: php, web-service, rest, libcurl, request

Bom dia a todos.
Pessoal, estou com um problema para comunicar com webservice de uma empresa de terceiros aqui onde trabalho. Explicando meio por cima, preciso enviar um relatório de transações com cupons que foram identificados com a opção de cashback e enviar via WS para esta empresa contabilizar e gerar o crédito na conta dos clientes. A geração do arquivo e tudo mais está pronto, o problema está no envio do arquivo para o WS.

**Segue meu código que envia o arquivo:**

```
        // URL COMPLETA: https://integration-staging.meliuz.com.br/base2/superrocha/
        $url = 'https://integration-staging.meliuz.com.br/base2/superrocha/';

        // O Token que é privado e não posso compartilhar aqui
        $header = array(
            'Content-Type: text/plain',
            "Authorization: {$aConfEnvio['token']}",
        );
        // $path é o caminho para o arquivo que gerei. Caso precise posso 
        // postar o conteúdo
        $args['file_contents'] = file_get_contents($path);

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $result = curl_exec ($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $erro = curl_errno($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


        var_dump($result);
        var_dump($info);
        var_dump($erro);
        exit();
```

**Segue retorno da execução:**

```
string(1393) "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 04 Jan 2018 11:52:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1106
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Accept-Encoding

SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
    at parse (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
    at invokeCallback (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
    at done (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:307:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapped (/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/transaction/tracer/index.js:183:28)
    at IncomingMessage.wrappedEmit [as emit] (/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/transaction/tracer/index.js:220:46)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
    at process.wrappedFunction (/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/transaction/tracer/index.js:284:51)
"
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(59) "https://integration-staging.meliuz.com.br/base2/superrocha/"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(24) "text/html; charset=utf-8"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(400)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(287)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(265)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(19)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(1.329416)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.509034)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.50954)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.609594)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(688)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1106)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(831)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(517)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1106)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(688)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(1.303348)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(12) "54.94.158.77"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(443)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(12) "192.168.0.85"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(37200)
}

int(0)
```

Ai vem um mistério... o problema não está no WS deles porque quando eu testo pelo PHPStorm Rest Client ele funciona.
Segue print:

**Request**
[image: Request]
**Resposta**
[image: Resposta]

O retorno na resposta já é da validação lá no WS deles.
Alguém tem alguma dica?
Estou aberto a sugestões de melhorias ou outras formas de fazer isso. Lembrando apenas que tem que ser em **PHP**.

Obrigado desde já pessoal.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo erro:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
>       at parse (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)

Eu deduzo que o problema seja ao usar o comando `JSON.parse()` que deve ser usado para converter uma `string`contendo notação JSON em um `objeto` JavaScript.

Teria de debugar nesse ponto para ver como está sendo chamado a variável que está tentando ser convertida para JSON.

Espero que isso possa te ajudar.